# Differentiating Delta function on the light cone

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

How one differentiates a delta-function of a space-time interval? Namely,
$$[\partial_t^2 - \partial_x^2 - \partial_y^2 - \partial_z^2] \, \delta(t^2-x^2-y^2-z^2) \, .$$
Somewhere I saw that the result was $4\pi\delta^{(4)}(x)$, however, have no idea on how to obtain it.

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/614754/2451